# python3 Defining __repr__ on a function name

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Apologies: this question is very unclear. I have rewritten it in a form that is much clearer, I hope. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066737](http:////https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066737). I really wanted to delete this question, but the system advised me not to do so.

I'm struggling with defining `__repr__()` in my class. I have a class member `self.lbl` which can be the null string '', or a one character string 'a' or a function name. My failing code is

```
def __repr__(self):
    lbl = self.lbl
    if isinstance(lbl,str) and len(lbl) <= 1:
        out = "'" + lbl + "'" 
    elif type(lbl).__name__ == 'function':
        out = repr(lbl.__name__)
    return out
```

Suppose that `f` is a defined function, and I write `x=f`. Then I want to extract the information `f` from `MyClass(x)` and `print(MyClass(x))` should just give me `f`, not `'f'`

Comment: Huh?  Whatever you're trying to do, don't mess with `__repr__` for that

Comment: Why are you checking the type of the *name*, instead of the thing itself?

Comment: btw, `out = "'" + lbl + "'" ` should probably just be `out = repr(lbl)`, no?

Comment: Also, `elif type(lbl).__name__ == 'function':` is just not the way to do this. In python, use `isinstance` or heck, even `type(obj) is SomeType` to check for types. This isn't Javascript :) ! You can `from types import FunctionType` or simply use `FunctionType = type(lambda : None)` and then use `isinstance(lbl, FunctionType)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you mean something like:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, lbl):
        self.lbl = lbl

    def __repr__(self):
        lbl = self.lbl
        if callable(lbl):
            lbl = lbl.__name__
        else:
            lbl = repr(lbl)
        return f"MyClass({lbl})"
```

if tested with:

```
def foo():
    return bar

print(MyClass('a'))
print(MyClass(lambda x: x * 2))
print(MyClass(foo))
```

it gives:

```
MyClass('a')
MyClass(<lambda>)
MyClass(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Types like `str` and `lambda` have their own `__repr__` already.  Just use that.  Note that `eval(repr(obj))` creating the original object is a recommendation, not a requirement.

Example (Python 3.6+):

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self,lbl):
...         self.lbl = lbl
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f'MyClass(lbl={self.lbl!r})'
...
>>> MyClass('')
MyClass(lbl='')
>>> MyClass('a')
MyClass(lbl='a')
>>> MyClass(lambda x: x * 2)
MyClass(lbl=<function <lambda> at 0x000001E0E288E730>)
```

Comment: I need to rewrite my question completely to make my aim clear. I wanted to delete this question, but the system warned me against doing so